# Password change prompt for SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, password, sftp

In our Linux server we have implemented password aging policy. On expiration SSH gives prompt for changing password on successful authentication.

However SFTP doesn't give the prompt to change password. It will disconnect with `Connection closed` error. So users have to connect to SSH to change password.

Any way to make SFTP also prompt for password change like SSH ?

Comment: http://www.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/securityfocus/Secure_Shell/2004-06/0029.html

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to accomplish that.